# NDSolve accuracy

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods

We're asking NDSolve to solve x'' + x == 0 to 20 digits, but when we compare to the true solution, we only see 9 correct digits. Are we not using NDSolve correctly?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == v[t], v'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, v[0] == 0}, {x, v},
    {t, 0, 100}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
Plot[(x[t] - Cos[t]) /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: Do you compute the correct solution correctly ?

Comment: haha, do you compute it accurately.

Comment: Setting Goals to 20 digits, but only getting 9 digits out of NDSolve

Comment: HOW DO YOU COMPUTE THE ANALYTICAL SOLUTION?

Comment: Are you saying that there are issues with how accurately Cos[t] is evaluated in the difference x[t]-Cos[t]?

Comment: Oh, I see, we need to set working precision in the plot command.

Comment: Yep, you need to make sure that it is computed to 20 digits as well.